# How to add more than two controls in a placeholder dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello Everyone I want to add one label on each gridview that I generate dynamically. Please tell how can i add label with each gridview I am using this code

```
  private void CreateGrid()
    {
        DataSet dsServiceId;
        dsServiceId = FetchServiceId();
        int countServices;
        countServices = dsServiceId.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        //----
        Table t = new Table();
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        //---
        for (int i = 0; i < countServices; i++)
        {
            int serviceid = Convert.ToInt32(dsServiceId.Tables[0].Rows[i]["pServiceID"].ToString());
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ezyMobile"].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Ezy_opWiseSaleAll", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serviceid", serviceid);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            gv.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            gv.ID = "_gridview" + i;
            gv.DataSource = ds;
            gv.DataBind();
            //-----
            if (i % 4 == 0)
            {
                row = new TableRow();
            }
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Controls.Add(gv);
            row.Controls.Add(cell);
            t.Controls.Add(row);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t);
        //------
    }
    }
    protected DataSet FetchServiceId()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ezyMobile"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct pServiceID from tbProcTransactions",con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;

    }
```

I want to add some information about the each gridview that generate dynamically.
Thanks

Comment: You need to put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using` blocks so they'll be cleaned up in a timely manner, or if exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

What, exactly, are you confused about?  Adding a Label to the placeholder will follow the same type of pattern that you used to add the Table control.

So, right after you add the Table you created, you would do this:

```
...
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t);

Label myLabel = new Label(); // create a new label
myLabel.Text = "Some stuff about this GridView"; // add some text
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myLabel); // add it to the PlaceHolder
```